# Is there a better way to redirect through a state using ui-router?

Tags: angular-ui-router

Is there a better way to redirect through a state without using $urlRouterProvider? I want to redirect to elsewhere after going through the base.home state.

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('base', {
            url: '/base',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                "mainbase": {
                    templateUrl: 'ng/apps/base/views/header.html',
                    controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
                }
            },
        })
        .state('base.home', {
            url: '',
            views: {
                "baseHeaderView": {
                    template: 'base home, you should not be here',
                    controller: function($state) {
                        // Can this be accomplished better?
                        $state.go('base.elsewhere');
                    }   
                }
            }
        })
        .state('base.elsewhere',{
          url: '/elsewhere'
          //I want to redirect to here after going through the base.home state
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark your redirect state with an attribute, then add a global listener for `$stateChangeStart` and conditionally supersede the transition.

This does the redirection in place of the original transition, so 'base.home' isn't even activated temporarily.  If you

```
 app.run($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, toState, params) {
      if (toState.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(toState.redirectTo, params);
      }
    });
  }

  app.config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('base', {
            url: '/base',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                "mainbase": {
                    templateUrl: 'ng/apps/base/views/header.html',
                    controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
                }
            },
        })
        .state('base.home', {
            url: '',
            views: {
                "baseHeaderView": {
                    template: 'base home, you should not be here',
                    controller: function($state) {
                        // Can this be accomplished better?
                        $state.go('base.elsewhere');
                    }   
                }
            },
            redirectTo: 'base.elsewhere'
        })
        .state('base.elsewhere',{
          url: '/elsewhere'
          //I want to redirect to here after going through the base.home state
        });
  });
```

Comment: I needed base.home to be activated.

Comment: Then you should listen to $stateChangeSuccess instead. Why do you want the redirect state activated?